# MySQL Service dosent start anymore

Tags: mysql, service, debian

When i try to start mysql with:

```
service mysql start

 /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Then it takes a while and this shows:

[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mariadb.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!

Now when I go to journalctl -xe it shows:

```
Feb 18 14:54:43 mail systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Feb 18 14:55:24 mail systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 18 14:55:24 mail systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.1.37 database server.

Feb 18 14:56:14 mail mysqld[8490]: 2019-02-18 14:56:14 140312205868416 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.37-MariaDB-0+deb9u1) starting as process 8490 ...
Feb 18 14:57:44 mail systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Feb 18 14:58:25 mail systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 18 14:58:25 mail systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.1.37 database server.
```

I cant login anymore in root user. Then I start mysql in safemode and change the password.

Comment: For how long were things working, and did you recently make any changes to your MySQL configuration which might cause this problem?

Comment: I dont no, i dosent use the root user in mysql. And in the configuration i dosent change anything.

Answer (score 1):

this error mostly come when you moved from mysql to mariadb. here is the solution you need to run three commands and your application will start working again.

- echo "/usr/sbin/mysqld { }" > /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
- apparmor_parser -v -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld systemctl
- restart mariadb